# Duplicate calls to http in Angular on Subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs

I'm new to angular and trying to implement a dashboard application. The dashboard contains 50+ different charts so I decided to capture all the data of these charts user one API call, the json file is as follows

```
{
"site": "bje",
"date": "2018-03-09T00:00:00",
"charts": [
    {
        "code": "INDK-01",
        "dataset": [
            {
                "name": "Actual",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "label": "05 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 351,
                        "date": "2018-01-05T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "12 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 373,
                        "date": "2018-01-12T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "19 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 353,
                        "date": "2018-01-19T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "26 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 379,
                        "date": "2018-01-26T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "02 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 356,
                        "date": "2018-02-02T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "09 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 371,
                        "date": "2018-02-09T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "16 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 371,
                        "date": "2018-02-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "23 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 368,
                        "date": "2018-02-23T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "02 Mar 2018",
                        "value": 369,
                        "date": "2018-03-02T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "09 Mar 2018",
                        "value": 371,
                        "date": "2018-03-09T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Budget",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "label": "05 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-01-05T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "12 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-01-12T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "19 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-01-19T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "26 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-01-26T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "02 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-02-02T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "09 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-02-09T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "16 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-02-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "23 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-02-23T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "02 Mar 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-03-02T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "09 Mar 2018",
                        "value": 331.02,
                        "date": "2018-03-09T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Target",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "label": "05 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-01-05T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "12 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-01-12T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "19 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-01-19T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "26 Jan 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-01-26T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "02 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-02-02T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "09 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-02-09T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "16 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-02-16T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "23 Feb 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-02-23T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "02 Mar 2018",
                        "value": 0,
                        "date": "2018-03-02T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "09 Mar 2018",
                        "value": 331.02,
                        "date": "2018-03-09T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },..............etc
] }
```

The service .ts file contain a function that return the data as follows:

```
getDashboardData(): Observable<ProcessedData>{

return this._http.get<ProcessedData>(this.baseUrl)
  .map(res => res);
  }
```

As well I have created one re-usable component which accept an input of chart code (ex. "INDK-01" in above json sample) an in ngOnInit I have this code

```
ngOnInit() {    
this._service.getDashboardData(this.selectedSite, this.selectedDate)
  .subscribe(res => {          
      this.BudgetData = res.charts.find(x => x.code == this.chartId)
      .dataset.find(x => x.name == 'Budget')
      .data
      .sort();
       this.TargetData = res.charts.find(x => x.code == this.chartId)
      .dataset.find(x => x.name == 'Target')
      .data
      .sort();
.
.
.
});
```

in dashboard home component I add multiple  
the problem that it makes multiple calls to the API everytime I load dashboard page, is there any way to avoid that? like for example store the data in a global object and from each chart will filter to get the proper data.

Comment: You can sotre the data inside this service you have created. When you access this getDashboardData, first you check if it has data. If it doesn't, do the http request and store there. Then you return the data from this stored value (in a service's instance variable).

Comment: Anywaym there are other ways, such as using a global state container (you can read about redux, @ngrx, etc...) or using a local storage from the browser. Anyone of those has its pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first `shareReplay(1)` your observable something like following to cache the data:

```
const sharedOb = this._service.getDashboardData(this.selectedSite, this.selectedDate).shareReplay(1)

sharedOb.subscribe(x=>{
// do your work here
})
```

Now you can subscribe to `sharedOb` as many as times you want, there will only be one server round-trip.

Comment: this code will run in each chart component, isn't it??? the values will be different from one chart into another based on the id I pass.
the goal is to get all the json response and store them in an array and filter the data by chartId, the data will be refreshed only if selectedSite and/or selectedDate changed then it has to refresh data again using the API from DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ".share".

```
this._service.getDashboardData(this.selectedSite, this.selectedDate).subscribe(res => 
{
  this.BudgetData = res.charts.find(x => x.code == this.chartId)
  .dataset.find(x => x.name == 'Budget')
  .data
  .sort();
   this.TargetData = res.charts.find(x => x.code == this.chartId)
  .dataset.find(x => x.name == 'Target')
  .data
  .sort();
}).share();
```

Comment: this code will run in each chart component, isn't it??? the values will be different from one chart into another based on the id I pass.
the goal is to get all the json response and store them in an array and filter the data by chartId, the data will be refreshed only if selectedSite and/or selectedDate changed then it has to refresh data again using the API from DB.